# How to use SQL's LIKE on a guid in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, guid

In SQL Server, `uniqueidentifier` columns can be used like strings with the LIKE comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE GuidColumn LIKE '4c38e01e%'
```

**How can I use this feature in Entity Framework?**

I want something like this

```
context.Table.Where(x => x.StringColumn.Contains("some string"))
```

but for a Guid column instead for string columns:

```
context.Table.Where(x => x.GuidColumn ???? "4c38e01e")
```

Comment: A total shot in the dark since I'm not set up to test, but did you try `.ToString().Contains(...)`?

Comment: Tried that, but got `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: It seems as if the data modelling is a bit off if a *portion* of the GUID has some kind of meaning - that portion ought to be stored in its own column.

Comment: It's not that the GUID portions have their own meaning. It's just that my client has to do a lot of searching by GUIDs, and he wants to be able to double-click a portion of the GUID in the browser, and then search by that portion, because in his DB, a portion of 8 GUID characters is unique in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no way to convert Guid to string on the fly in EntityFramework. 
I'm aware of some workaraounds but they are not elegant to me though they may be helpful in your case:

1. Create a view in SQL server where you convert your Guid column to string. Then create a new entity and map it to the view. Now you have your guid column in a string represantation and can apply 'like' operator. The main drawback is query performance.
2. Create a PERSISTENT calculated column of string type. Use convert expression to convert your Guid to string. Query performance would be the same as for an ordinary string column, but it will take a bit longer to insert records into your table.
3. If this is not the only filter applied to your data source then maybe you can apply your GUID LIKE operation when the data is already in memory.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this by creating a stored procedure in the database that handled the 'like' clause in the database, and mapping the procedure results to my entity from the edmx. So my stored proc is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetDevicesWhereGuidContains] 
@partialGuidString as varchar (5)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * from devices where [Guid] like '%' + @partialGuidString + '%'
END
```

Then, mapping the proc to the entity from the model browser:
http://entityframeworktutorial.net/data-read-using-stored-procedure.aspx#.UT0F96GG1e4

Then it's obvious from there;

```
List<Device> devices = context.spGetDevicesWhereGuidContains("8").ToList();
```

Not ideal, but does the job.