# What are the rules for using an ADO Recorset filter with a SQL Server uniqueidentifier column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi, ado

I'm trying to use the ADO Filter property to filter a Recordset with a `uniqueidentifier` column.  I'm connecting to SQL Server 2008 using ADO on Windows 7, using the `SQLOLEDB.1` provider.

I create a Recordset and use it to send the SQL query to the server. Then I set the ADO `Recordset.Filter` property. I get errors no matter what I've tried for the Filter.

If I try

```
[column name] = '5D9C83FB-E758-0D4B-B1C7-E751D951B67C'
```

I get

> Filter cannot be opened.

If I try

```
[column name] like '%5D9C83FB-E758-0D4B-B1C7-E751D951B67C%'
```

I get

> Invalid class string.

(Note: I've left out any required double-quotes for clarity. I'm able to search other types of string columns so the quoting isn't the problem.)

I am using Delphi XE2, but I think that's probably not relevant as I'm creating my ADO object directly rather than use any of their wrapper code. I have no problem with the `Filter` property on any of the various string type columns, just `uniqueidentifier`.

My basic question is if you can make this work, how do you do it (short of converting the column to a string during querying)? The more general question is what are the rules around using `uniqueidentifier` columns with the `Filter` property. I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Did you try `'{5D9C83FB-E758-0D4B-B1C7-E751D951B67C}'`?

Comment: See comment on your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of those cases you're treating them like strings. I suggest trying wrapping the GUID value in curly braces:

```
[column name] = '{5D9C83FB-E758-0D4B-B1C7-E751D951B67C}'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the equal operator.  I still can't figure out if there's a way to make the LIKE operator work.  Tried a few things with the curly braces but it didn't like any of them.  I'll mark your answer as accepted if nobody posts the actual rules (hopefully with some citation) about Filter and uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Does that really matter?  Okay, because a user read it out to you over the phone and you're pretty sure they transposed a couple of letters.  This is basically part of a larger ad hoc querying system.  If I can't use LIKE, so be it.  But if I can, I'd LIKE to know how.  :D

Comment: The only way you are going to be able to use `LIKE` is to convert it to a string so you can do a string compare.

Comment: By which you mean change it in the originating SQL statement, correct?  Just asking for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi (and most other frameworks), you cannot filter GUID locally in a RecordSet with syntax similar to LIKE with strings. To the frameworks, GUIDs are just a bunch of bytes, not a string.

You have to do the filtering on the server side using the LIKE syntax that SQL Server itself supports (an example of the syntax is in [How to use SQL's LIKE on a guid in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118654/how-to-use-sqls-like-on-a-guid-in-entity-framework)).